# React Native: always gradlew clean before run react-native-run-android

Tags: react-native

If don't run `cd android && ./gradlew clean` before `react-native run-android` this fails with some error like:

> Failed to create folder: ...

or

> Failed to delete folder: ...

so I must run more times again to solve it.

Help me solve it without `gradlew clean`, please.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 37):

For clean android project run following command in macOS

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean
```

to re-run

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 18):

I'm having a similar problem since upgrading to RN 43. I haven't found the solution yet but realised that a clean in necessary before a successful build will occur.

Best solution for me so far is a batch script to start the project which includes gradlew clean

```
@echo on
cd (path to project/android folder) && ^
gradlew clean && ^
cd (path to project root folder) && ^
react-native run-android
```

commands:
1.cd (path to project/android folder)
2.gradlew clean
3. cd ..
4.react-native run-android

Comment: What is this `^` syntax?

Comment: @ReedSpool it allows a single statement to wrap onto the next line.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu Follow this guide work for me
`cd android` ->
`chmod +x gradlew` ->
`./gradlew clean` ->
`cd .. && react-native run-android`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. What worked for me was, on Windows, opening the command prompt as an administrator. The issue is that the script didn't have permission to delete a folder.

1. Hit the windows key
2. Type `Command Prompt`
3. Right click the Command Prompt result that pops up
4. Click "Run as administrator"
5. Click "yes" to the dialog that pops up "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to this device?"
6. In the Command Prompt `cd` to your project directory
7. run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution to the problem is to use "watchman" as the file-watcher, as seen here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9136#issuecomment-306486102

Answer (score 0):

changing the minSdkVersion from 16 to 21 in android/build.gradle + cd android ./gradlew clean - solved the problem it is working fine now